# php header working locally on xxamp but not on godaddy server

Tags: php, header

I want to redirect to an `adm/index.php` file `if($count==1)`, but the page just refreshes and stays on the same page.

I have tried several solutions to no avail:

1. checked for spaces before the beginning `<?php>`
2. removed all html links before the beginning `<?php>`

Everything works well locally on xxamp, but the problem is after uploading, there is no error message; just the same page refreshes and it is blank.

There are two functions which are called in the main program; the main program also contains some echos. Is it possible to make the headers work?

```
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM adminlogin WHERE username = '$myusername' and password ='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql); // from adminlogin table, ngetasacco
$sql2="SELECT * FROM memberslogin WHERE username = '$myusername' and password ='$mypassword'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2); // from the memberslogin table, ngetasacco

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$count2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)// only the admin
{
$_SESSION['myusername'] = myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = mypassword;
header("location: adm/index.php");
}
elseif($count2==1)// any registered member with access
{
$_SESSION['myusername'] = myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = mypassword;
header("location: adm/member.php");
}
else {
echo "<musuya>Wrong username or Password</musuya><br/><br/>";
//echo md5($mypassword);
//$m=md5($mypassword);
usernamePass();
}
ob_end_flush();
}// end of function auth()
function usernamePass()
{
echo "<form method='post' action=" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . ">";
echo " username <input type='text' name='username' /><br/><br/>";
echo "password <input type='password' name='password' value=''/><br/>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Login' />";
}// end of function usernamePass()
//++++++++++++++++++++++++++main program
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
{ 
echo"username and pasword cannot be empty</br></br>";
usernamePass();
}
if(!(empty($_POST["username"])) && !(empty($_POST["password"])))
{
auth();
}
if(!empty($_GET['status']))
{
echo '<div>You have been logged out!</div>';
}      
//++++++++++++++++++++++++ end of main program
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
?>
```

### connections/db_connect.php

```
<?php
$host="";// Host name
$username="";//Mysql username
$password="";//Mysql password
$db_name="";//Database name
$tbl_name="";//Table name
//Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");//or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");//or die("cannot select DB");
//echo "connected to server and dbase";
?>
```

Comment: You are not doing any error checking. http://php.net/mysql_error

Comment: there should be some errors, anyway make sure your output buffering is enabled or check [ob_start](http://us1.php.net/ob_start) and add it to your code

Comment: no am not doing any error checking...Pekka

Comment: i just included the rest of the code...

Answer (score 0):

Add  `ob_end_flush();` at to bottom of the file and check it

```
<?php
function auth(){
ob_start();
include"connections/db_connect.php";
// Define $myusername and $mypassword
$myusername=md5($_POST['username']);
$mypassword=md5($_POST['password']);
// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM adminlogin WHERE username = '$myusername' and password     = '$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql); // from adminlogin table, ngetasacco
$sql2="SELECT * FROM memberslogin WHERE username = '$myusername' and     password = '$mypassword'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2); // from the memberslogin table, ngetasacco
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$count2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
//if($count==1){
if($count==1)// only the admin
{
    $_SESSION['myusername'] = myusername;
    $_SESSION['mypassword'] = mypassword;
    //header("location: login_success.php");
    header("location: adm/index.php");
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: this the rest of the code}
elseif($count2==1)// any registered member with access
{
$_SESSION['myusername'] = myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = mypassword;
header("location: adm/member.php");
}
else {
echo "<musuya>Wrong username or Password</musuya><br/><br/>";
   //echo md5($mypassword);
    //$m=md5($mypassword);
usernamePass();
}
ob_end_flush();
}// end of function auth()

Comment: it has ob_end_flush(); before the end of function auht();

Comment: try ob_start(); before start function of auth(); and add ob_end_flush(); after end of this function

Comment: i just tried putting ob_start(); before the start of auth(); and at the end, but no change.... i dont if i should wait for some time maybe the server refreshes

Comment: i gave the server (godaddy) sometime, but still 12 hours later still the same problem

Comment: Try to fetch error by error_reporting(-1); it will show the exact error

Comment: thanks for ur reply, i think the problem may be with the main program that calls the function auth(), this codes are after the codes above. theres another function after the auth(); and then the main program which calls the two functions. the main program has echo some text. do i put the whole codes u check where i can rectify?

Comment: please view the code again i just included the rest with the 2 functions... is there a way of making the headers work?